# save each individual image in grid image

Tags: python, image, generator, pytorch, save-image

I want to save each individual image in grid image. How should I modify this code? Or is there an answer that I would like to refer to?

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Generator, self).__init__()

    self.label_emb = nn.Embedding(opt.n_classes, opt.latent_dim)

    self.init_size = opt.img_size // 4  # Initial size before upsampling
    self.l1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(opt.latent_dim, 128 * self.init_size ** 2))

    self.conv_blocks = nn.Sequential(
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
        nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 128, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128, 0.8),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 64, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64, 0.8),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(64, opt.channels, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.Tanh(),
    )
```

..

```
generator = Generator()
```

..

```
def sample_image(n_row, batches_done):
    """Saves a grid of generated digits ranging from 0 to n_classes"""

    # Sample noise
    z = Variable(FloatTensor(np.random.normal(0, 1, (n_row ** 2, opt.latent_dim))))

    # Get labels ranging from 0 to n_classes for n rows
    labels = np.array([num for _ in range(n_row) for num in range(n_row)])
    labels = Variable(LongTensor(labels))
    gen_imgs = generator(z, labels)
    save_image(gen_imgs.data[:i], "images/%d.png" % batches_done, nrow=1, normalize=True)
```

Comment: you haven't provided the code for `generator` or `save_image` so its really not possible to answer this question without guessing about your data format.

Comment: I could guess you're using torchvision's `save_image` but then I would also guess you're familiar with [`torchvision.utils.make_grid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/utils.html#torchvision.utils.make_grid)

Comment: I added my generator code. Thank you!

Comment: You use a mysterious `i` in `sample_image` not sure where this comes from or where it's defined. If you pass `torchvision.utils.save_image` the output of your network (unsliced) it should automagically save a grid.